# Haskell List and Control.Lens

Tags: list, haskell, haskell-lens

I'm writing an AST library for a simple "dynamically typed" language.  I have written my syntax tree and parser.  Now I'm working on manipulating the AST, and I am interested in using the lens package for that purpose.

Consider

```
data Obj = Obj !(Map Text Obj)
         | Arr ![Obj]
```

I can write a lens to manipulate object fields pretty easily:

```
field t (Obj m) = m^.at t
field _ _       = Nothing
```

but I have no idea where to start for manipulating Arr elements.  I'd like a lens along the lines of:

```
arrIx :: Int -> Obj -> Maybe Obj
arrIx i (Arr objs) = objs^.someLensHere i 
   where someLensHere i = undefined
```

I will change my Obj representation for expedience, but it would still be helpful to know how to index on lists using lens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To index lists using lens, use [ix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix). Example:

```
>>> let myList = [1,4,2,212,5]
>>> myList ^? ix 2  -- (^?) gets the result as a Maybe
Just 2
>>> preview (ix 10) myList -- preview is the non-operator version of (^?)
Nothing
>>> myList & ix 3 .~ 4  -- Set the 4zh element to 4.
[1,4,2,4,5]
>>> myList & ix 10 .~ 5  -- Inserting new elements is not possible
[1,4,2,212,5]
```

There is also another question about the [Difference between at and ix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414177/what-is-the-difference-between-ix-and-at-in-the-lens-library-of-haskell/18414280#18414280).