# Default value if it doesn't exist in map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, haskell-lens

For my purposes, I need a map-like container with 'properties' of some kind. It is possible that my objects can have different properties. To access the properties, I decided to use [Control.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.1), it's very interesting. But I can't find a lens-like way for such logic: on access to property, if it doesn't exist, add default value instead, and return the new one. But if it's there, just use it.

In other words, the **prop_test** should return True:

```cs
type PropertyMap = Map.Map Int String
data Properties = Properties { _propertyMap :: PropertyMap }
  deriving (Eq)

makeLenses ''Properties

emptyProperties = Properties Map.empty

propertyLens pIndex = propertyMap . at pIndex . traverse

property1 = propertyLens 1
property2 = propertyLens 2
property3 = propertyLens 3

obj1Properties :: State Properties ()
obj1Properties = do
    property1 .= "Property1 value"
    property2 .= "Property2 value"

obj2Properties :: State Properties ()
obj2Properties = do
    property1 .= "Property1 value"
    property3 .= "Property3 value"

prop_test = op1 /= emptyProperties
    where
        op1 = execState obj1Properties emptyProperties
```

But now, op1 is equal to emptyProperties. For default value, I could use Data.Default. How can I handle this? Or should I use another method maybe? For example, a wrapper function in State monad which unpacks and checks the properties existence for me.

Also, could you give links to real world examples of Control.Lens (or another lens package), please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make `Properties` and instance of 'Monoid' with `mempty` equal to `emptyProperties` and `mappend` something sensible like the union of the two maps then the Lens library will just do the right thing.

The alternative is to use one of the combinators specifically designed for traversals (lenses that can return 0 or more results) and deal with the missing case then. See the documentation for `(^?)` which would produce a `Maybe t` or `(^..)` which will give you `[t]`.

Comment: On a pedantic note, `^..` and `^.` are for `Fold`s of which `Traversal`s are a super set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [John F. Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163177/john-f-miller) answer, being thinking about it, I realized, I do need the wrapper functions to simplify using of properties. So, the code will be:

```
type PropertyMap = Map.Map Int String
data Properties = Properties { _propertyMap :: PropertyMap }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

emptyProperties = Properties Map.empty

makeLenses ''Properties

newtype PAccessor = PAccessor { pKey :: Int }

property1 = PAccessor 1
property2 = PAccessor 2
property3 = PAccessor 3

(|=) accessor v = do
    ps <- get
    put $ propertyMap . at (pKey accessor) ?~ v $ ps

setProperty = (|=)

getProperty accessor = do
    ps <- get
    return $ ps ^. propertyMap . ix (pKey accessor)

maybeProperty accessor = do
    ps <- get
    return $ ps ^. propertyMap . at (pKey accessor)

obj1Properties :: State Properties String
obj1Properties = do
    property1 |= "Property1 value"
    property2 |= "Property2 value"
    p1Val <- getProperty property1
    p3Val <- getProperty property3 -- Returns default value (empty string)
    return (p1Val ++ p3Val)

obj2Properties :: State Properties String
obj2Properties = do
    property2 |= "Property2 value"
    property3 |= "Property3 value"
    Nothing <- maybeProperty property1
    Just p2Val <- maybeProperty property2
    return p2Val

expectedProps1 = Properties $ Map.fromList [ (1, "Property1 value")
                                           , (2, "Property2 value") ]

expectedProps2 = Properties $ Map.fromList [ (2, "Property2 value")
                                           , (3, "Property3 value") ]

prop_test1 = (props == expectedProps1) && (val == "Property1 value")
    where
        (val, props) = runState obj1Properties emptyProperties

prop_test2 = (props == expectedProps2) && (val == "Property2 value")
    where
        (val, props) = runState obj2Properties emptyProperties

prop_test3 = val == "Property2 value"
    where
        val = evalState obj2Properties emptyProperties
```

All test functions pass, i.e., results are equal to True.
As a bonus, the code shows the difference between `ix` and `at`. I'll try to improve this solution, but it looks acceptable for now.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414177/what-is-the-difference-between-ix-and-at-in-the-lens-library-of-haskell