# Idiomatic style with lenses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm still not fully understanding lenses.

```
applicationState = (
    'a',
    'b',
    (   M.fromList $ zip [1..3]  [11,22,33],
        M.fromList $ zip [4,5,6] [44,55,66],
        M.fromList $ zip [7,8,9] [M.fromList $ zip [2,3,4] ["77","777","7777"],
        M.fromList $ zip [2,3,4] ["88","888","8888"],
        M.fromList $ zip [2,3,4] ["99","999","9999"]] )
    )
```

Is there a more lens-idiomatic way of doing this:

```
λ> view (_3 . _3 . at 9) applicationState >>= view (at 4) >>= return . ('9':)
Just "99999"
```

Comment: `preview (_3 . _3 . ix 9 . ix 4 . to ('9':)) applicationState`

Comment: Reformatted it's easy to see that you do `M.fromList $ zip xs ys` a lot, maybe you should also consider tacking `where fromLists xs ys = M.fromList $ zip xs ys` just below the definition for `applicationState` and replacing all instances with `fromLists`.  It'll save you a bit of space, at the very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `traverse :: Traversal (Maybe a) (Maybe b) a b` and then use [`preview`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preview):

```
preview (_3 . _3 . at 9 . traverse . at 4 . traverse . to ('9':)) applicationState
```

Because [`ix i = at i . traverse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414177/what-is-the-difference-between-ix-and-at-in-the-lens-library-of-haskell), this can also be written as:

```
preview (_3 . _3 . ix 9 . ix 4 . to ('9':)) applicationState
```

You can also modify that way, but if any of the `at`'s fail, nothing will be changed (you cannot insert new elements in your map using a `Traversal`).

---

Another way is to use [`non :: a -> Lens' (Maybe a) a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non). This only works if the first map   (accessed by the lens `_3._3`) never contains an empty map as a value and the second map never contains an empty string as a value. So the following value would be invalid for applicationState:

```
('a', 'b', 
  ( M.fromList $ zip [1..3] [11,22,33]
  , M.fromList $ zip [4,5,6] [44,55,66]
  , M.fromList $ zip [7..9] [M.empty] -- No value of this map may be the empty map
  )
)
```

With `non`, your example can be written as:

```
view (_3 . _3 . at 9 . non M.empty . at 4 . non "" . to ('9':)) applicationState
```

This also allows inserting new entries via setting (if you set and the keys 4 or 9 don't exist yet, they will be created) and deleting entries (if you set to the value "", the key 4 will be removed, and if the map is empty after removing that key, the key 9 will also be removed).