# How to make setters in 2D Array Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, setter

I currently have a 2D array declared as:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed
listArray ((0,0), (9,9)) (replicate 100 'f') ∷  UArray (Int, Int) Char
```

I am trying to set a value in this array from a set of coordinates, `(x, y)` stored as a tuple, changing the value into a `t`, instead of an `f`.  I have fooled around with lenses, however, I have had no success with them.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably want to look at the `Ixed` class in [`Control.Lens.At`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-At.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it right now

Comment: It appears that Control.Lens.At is used for Lists, not Arrays unfortunately

Comment: it can be used for lots of things, but you need `Ixed`, which can be used for even more.

Comment: The examples in the documentation may show lists, but there are many other instances, including for arrays. Look at the instance list right under the class definition.

Comment: Related, but perhaps more depth than necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414177/what-is-the-difference-between-ix-and-at-in-the-lens-library-of-haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access individual elements of an array with `lens`, you need to use the `ix` method of the `Ixed` class, defined in [`Control.Lens.At`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-At.html). If you define

```
fooArray :: UArray (Int, Int) Char
fooArray = listArray ((0,0), (9,9)) (replicate 100 'f')
```

then, firing up GHCi,

```
> fooArray ^? ix (1,2)
Just 'f'
> let fooArray' = fooArray & ix (1,2) .~ 't'
> fooArray' ^? ix (1,2)
Just 't'
```

Note that editing arrays like this is pretty inefficient if the arrays are large; if you need high speed or lots of array edits, you may want to consider a different structure.

The easiest ways to smash an array flat are the `elems` function from `Data.Array.Unboxed` or `toList` from `Data.Foldable`. If what those give you is sideways, you can probably patch it up with `ixmap`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get
`Not in scope: ^?`
`Perhaps you meant one of these:`
`^ (imported from Prelude), ^^ (imported from Prelude)`
From that statement

Comment: @anon, that's defined elsewhere; you'll get that *and* `Ixed` if you import `Control.Lens`.

Comment: Final error (I hope) `parse error in let binding: missing required "in"` I believe this is simply because I am doing something stupid with binding the value using `let`

Comment: @anon, that was part of a GHCi session, which handles `let` differently. In a module, you'd just write `fooArray' = fooArray & ix (1,2) .~ 't'` (preferably with a type signature above it), and leave out the `let`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks so much for your time and patients!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest [update function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#g:5) for arrays is `(//)`, which has this type:

```
(//) :: (IArray a e, Ix i) => a i e -> [(i, e)] -> a i e
```

For example:

```
Data.Array.Unboxed> listArray (0, 4) "abcde" // [(1, 'f')] :: UArray Int Char
array (0,4) [(0,'a'),(1,'f'),(2,'c'),(3,'d'),(4,'e')]
```

You can access particular elements with `(!)`:

```
Data.Array.Unboxed> it ! 1
'f'
```